# How can I create an Excel report on Acumatica Framework?

Tags: c#, excel, export, report, acumatica

I am trying to create an Excel document with information from the page using a customized button. The Excel document should be open and then it's up to the user to save it - Similarly as it is done with the Export to Excel button embedded in some of the Acumatica grids.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225717/excel-file-generation-api-methods-exposed) article where something similar is requested. However, adding the object
`new PX.Export.Excel.Core.Package()`   fails as the library is not recognized. Maybe this was deprecated in the latest releases?

I created this console project

```html
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            // Make the object visible.
            excelApp.Visible = true; ;

            // Create a new, empty workbook and add it to the collection returned 
            // by property Workbooks. The new workbook becomes the active workbook.
            // Add has an optional parameter for specifying a praticular template. 
            // Because no argument is sent in this example, Add creates a new workbook. 
            excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

            excelApp.Cells[1, "A"] = "SNO";
            excelApp.Cells[2, "B"] = "A";
            excelApp.Cells[2, "C"] = "1122";

            Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
        }
    }
}
```

and works correctly. But in Acumatica I receive the following error

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the 
following error: 80070005 Access is denied.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881132/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add reference of PX.Export.dll (from AcumaticaSite -> Bin folder) in your extension library to work with `PX.Export.Excel.Core.Package()`.